# how do I get user input from the view and use it in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get the user's input PurchaseAmount from view and use that input for my logic, if the PurchaseAmount > CardFunds, then it'll print a message "Insufficient Funds", if the Purchase < CardFunds, it'll process to the next statement.

I declared the PurchaseAmount and CardFunds in my .cs file as such:

```
namespace Form6.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    public partial class User
    {
           
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; } 
        public int CardFunds { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

PurchaseAmount will be given by the user, CardFunds is an Int datatype value previously storeed in the database.

and below is what I have for the controller :

```
namespace Form6.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Authorize(Form6.Models.User userModel)
        {
            using (Form6Entities db = new Form6Entities())
            {
                var userDetails = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == userModel.Username && x.Password == userModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                var cardDetails = db.Users.Where(x=> x.FirstName == userModel.FirstName && x.LastName == userModel.LastName && x.CardNum == userModel.CardNum && x.ExpDate == userModel.ExpDate && x.CVV == userModel.CVV).FirstOrDefault();

                var fundStatus = db.Users.Where(x => x.CardFunds == userModel.CardFunds).FirstOrDefault();

                var purchaseAmount = 
                
                if (userDetails == null)
                {
                    userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Unauthorized for this transaction!";
                    return View("Index", userModel);
                }

                else if (PurchaseAmount > userModel.CardFunds)
                {
                    userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Insufficient Funds";
                    return View("Index", userModel);
                }
    
                else
                {
                    Session["userID"] = userDetails.UserID;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }

        }
```

all the other logics are working properly such as verifying username and password, and all the cardDetaills inputs
how should I declare the variable PurchaseAmount in the controller with the user's input from the view file

and this will be the view's code:

```
  <div id="login-div"> 
        @using(Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "Login",FormMethod.Post))
            {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-decoration:underline">Payment Gateway</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardNum) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNum)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardNum)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpDate) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpDate)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpDate)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CVV) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CVV)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CVV)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label class="field-validation-error">@Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.LoginErrorMessage) </label>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            }
```

Comment: Where is your `view`s code? Could you please shate your view

Comment: the view's code has been added

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

> How should I declare the variable PurchaseAmount in the controller with the user's input from the view file?

In this scenario you should have two models. One is your `User Base Model` and another for `Purchase info Model`. You can think of below model.

**UserPurchaseinfo Model:**

```
public class UserPurchaseinfo
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public int PurchaseAmount { get; set; }
        public int CardFunds { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** As you already have `User Model` should I have renamed as `UserPurchaseinfo` to reduce ambiguity.

**Modify Existing User Model:**

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CardNum { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpDate { get; set; }
        public string CVV { get; set; }

        public UserPurchaseinfo UserPurchaseinfo { get; set; }
    }
```

Note: As you noticed that we have added `UserPurchaseinfo` in `UserModel` class so that we can take input from same view.

**View:**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.UserModel

<div id="login-div">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("PostPaymetInfo", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong style="text-decoration:underline;margin-left:25px;">Payment Gateway</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}})
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",type = "password"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardNum) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNum,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardNum)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpDate) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpDate,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpDate)</td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CVV) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CVV,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CVV)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong style="text-decoration:underline;margin-left:25px;">User Purchase Info</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPurchaseinfo.PurchaseAmount) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPurchaseinfo.PurchaseAmount,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",type = "number"}})</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPurchaseinfo.CardFunds) </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPurchaseinfo.CardFunds,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",type = "number"}})</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

**View Output:**

[image]

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostPaymetInfo(UserModel paymentModel)
        {
            // You can check and validate all the property which you are sending from your view
            // Now Check your PurchaseAmount here whatever you are getting on paymentModel

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Final Output:**

[image]

Basically you need to add your `UserPurchaseinfo` into your `User Model` so that you can access both property on your `view` finally you can take input from there and can submit above way.